# Pandas dataframe average calculation

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that I would like to compute the average across columns.  I have the following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

Column 'A' repeats but not column 'B'.  I would like to compute the average of the values in column 'B' for the repeating numbers in column 'A'.  For example for the first value in column 'A' which is 1 the value in 'B' is 3 and the next value in column 'A' which is 1 the value in 'B' is 9 and the next is 4 and so on.  Then continue with 2 and 3 etc...

I was thinking that if I can move those values to columns then compute the average across columns it would be easier but I can't find a way to copy the values there.  Maybe there is an easier way?

This is what I would like :

[image: DF2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupby and mean()

```
df.groupby('A').B.mean()
```

As @fuglede mentioned

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

would work as well as there is only column B left for aggregation.
Either way you get

```
A
1    6.25
2    6.50
3    4.75
```

Comment: For OP's purposes, it might even be possible to skip the `.B` and just use `df.groupby('A').mean()`.

Comment: Yes for this case B is redundant, I usually use it to make my own code more readable:)

Comment: Wow...the power of pandas.  Thanks!